# Tooltip not shown when input class is rating

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, rating, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Tool tip is not shown when the `<input type="hidden" class="rating"/>`

Tool tip is shown when the `<input type="hidden" class="rating1"/>`

MY codes are here

```
<input type="hidden" class="rating"/>

        <script>
        $('.rating').rating({
        extendSymbol: function (rate) {
        $(this).tooltip({
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'Rate ' + rate
        });
        }
        });
        </script>

<input type="hidden" class="rating1"/>

        <script>
        $('.rating1').rating({
        extendSymbol: function (rate) {
        $(this).tooltip({
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'Rate ' + rate
        });
        }
        });
        </script>

        <style>
        .symbol {
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 5px double white;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        }
        </style>
```

Comment: can you show a demo?

Comment: Sure

http://jsfiddle.net/MJGV2/80/

Comment: since we have rating function in bootstrap-rating.js, so this may be the conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the plugin you use (really, really stupidly) automatically assigns itself to any elements with a class of `.rating` with no parameters specified - see the last 4 lines of the code here: http://dreyescat.github.io/bootstrap-rating/bootstrap-rating.js

To fix you problem you simply need to give your `input` a different class so it uses the settings you provide, not the default parameter-less initialisation. Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="star-rating" /> <!-- note the changed class -->
```

```js
$('.star-rating').rating({
    extendSymbol: function(rate) {
        $(this).tooltip({
            container: 'body',
            placement: 'bottom',
            title: 'Rate ' + rate
        });
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/MJGV2/84/)

Also note that you can use a common class with a single jQuery selector to initialise the plugin on all elements. See the fiddle for an example.

I would also contact the plugin author and get them to remove the lines of code which automatically assign the plugin to anything with a `.rating` class - it's a really dumb thing to do in a plugin for public use.

Comment: so that is why is working for `class rating1` just like what OP said